# Sufficient statistics for bernoulli distribution

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, estimators, sufficient-statistics

Let $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n $ be a random sample of size $n$ where each $Y_i \sim \textrm{Bernoulli}(p), $ and
let $Y = \sum Y_i $ for $i = 1, \ldots, n.$

The estimator is $W= (Y+1)/(n+2). $

Is the estimator a sufficient statistics for **parameter p**?

I wanted to use the factorization theorem for this problem and wrote out the joint pdf, but I was stuck on rearranging the joint pdf

$$f(y_1,\ldots, y_n;p)= \prod p^{y_i}(1-p)^{1-y_i}. $$

Comment: Do you mean to ask whether the estimator is a *function* of the sufficient statistic? You know what the sufficient statistic is. Why not just show that W is *not* a function of that? To factorize the bernoulli likelihood, write it in exponential form, i.e. f(...) = exp(a + bT) where a, the ancillary parameter, does not depend on p.

Comment: $Y$ is [sufficient](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/452628). If you can find a formula to compute $Y$ from $W$--an easy task--then $W$ must be sufficient, too.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 1):

$$f(y_1...y_n;p)= \prod^n_{i=1}
 p^{y_i}(1-p)^{1-y_i}=$$

$$
= p^{y_1+...+y_n}(1-p)^{n-(y_1+...+y_n)}=
$$

$$
=p^{\sum y_i}(1-p)^{n-\sum y_i}
$$

By Neyman-Fisher factorization theorem the statistic $Y$ is sufficient for parameter $p$.

$Y = (n+2)W-1$, i.e. $W$ is a one-to-one function of a sufficient statistic $Y$. Hence, $W$ is also a sufficient statistic.